# Command line functionlity of eggjs

Tags: node.js, koa

Is it possible to develop commands which run the eggjs framework, so services etc. are available.

For example:

```
node bin/egg.js mycommand:start
```

Therefore I would like to create a "mycommand" class which has access to ctx, services, models etc.

I know this functionality from other frameworks (e.g. laravel) and it has been very helpful.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

- eggjs now support single thread mode, so you could just require and start it.
- or just write a eggjs plugin which expose a REPL